# How did 'Isabelle' (the theorem prover) get its name?

Tags: history, automated-theorem-proving, isabelle

The title says it all, but I'm curious because it isn't obvious how a theorem prover came to be named 'Isabelle'. Was it named for a person? I couldn't find out by some Google searches.

Comment: Have you tried asking on a Isabelle users mailing list?

Comment: I haven't - I've never used Isabelle myself - I've only read a paper that used it.

Comment: This question strikes me to be offtopic as it is about the history of a software artifact, not a CS artifact. That said, articles have been published about Isabelle so I'll let the community decide.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)) updated :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little google-fu (and my own memory) tells me [it was apparently named by Larry Paulson after Gerard Huet's daughter](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mjcg/Research94/node3.html).

Gerard Huet happens to be one of the people behind the less poetically named [Coq theorem prover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9rard_Huet#Biography).

Small world!

Comment: How is the name Coq less poetic? It's a pun on no less than three words (the Calculus of Constructions CoC, one of the founders of the theory Thierry Coquand, and the French word for *rooster* (which is an emblem of France, and most of the Coq founders were French)).

Comment: The Coq name is certainly *clever* (there was an additional constraint that academic programing languages were named after an animal, see e.g. Ocaml) but I *do* think it's a bit less poetic, especially given the additional pun (in English at least) that I wouldn't put beyond Gerhard Huet to be intentional.